# How to select the content from the element that I clicked on (using data attributes)

Tags: javascript

I am working with HTML and JS and I am trying to add a click event listener so that the `index = 0` value updates automatically on click.

Depending on which `.tab` element I click, the content inside of the `div.tab` should change to display either `Hello1`, `Hello2` or `Hello3`.
The first tab should display the tab content hello1 accordingly.

I have provided both with data attributes in the HTML. I want the corresponding `div.tab` content to be output if both have the same data attribute with vanilla JS.

**JS**

```
const tabbarContent = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-content");
const tabbarButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");
const index = 0;
tabbarContent[index].classList.add('active');
tabbarButtons[index].classList.add('active');
const dataAttribute1 = tabbarButtons[index].getAttribute("data-tab");
const dataAttribute2 = tabbarContent[index].getAttribute("data-tab");



function clickTab() {
  for (let index = 0; index.length; index++) {
    if (dataAttribute1[index] === dataAttribute2[index]) {
      dataAttribute2.classList.add("active");
    }
  }
}

tabbarButtons[index].addEventListener("click", clickTab);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="tab tab1" data-tab="1">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="tab tab2" data-tab="2">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="tab tab3" data-tab="3">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="tab-content content1" data-tab="1">
      <h1>Hello1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content content2" data-tab="2">
      <h1>Hello2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content content3" data-tab="3">
      <h1>Hello3</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks
Jessy

Comment: `for (let index = 0; index.length; index++)` makes no sense; I guess you meant `for (let index = 0; tabbarButtons.length; index++)` maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to achieve, you could do something like:

```js
const tabbarButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");
const tabbarContents = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-content");

tabbarButtons.forEach((tabBtn) => {
  tabBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    tabbarContents.forEach(tabCnt => {
      if (tabCnt.dataset.tab === tabBtn.dataset.tab) {
        tabCnt.classList.add('active');
      } else {
        tabCnt.classList.remove('active');
      }
    })
  });
})
```

```css
.tab {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="tab tab1" data-tab="1">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="tab tab2" data-tab="2">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="tab tab3" data-tab="3">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="tab-content content1" data-tab="1">
      <h1>Hello1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content content2" data-tab="2">
      <h1>Hello2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content content3" data-tab="3">
      <h1>Hello3</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```